# SaveChanges throws validation error in for loop

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I've an entity `Candidate`

```
public class Candidate
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public int Age { get; set; }
}
```

Now I've a list of `candidates` and I loop through the list and save them each individually. Now some items from the list don't match the validations given on the `Candidate` model.

```
var dbContext = new TestDbContext();

var list = new List<Candidate>
{
     new Candidate { Name = "", Age = 20 },
     new Candidate { Name = "Tom" , Age = 25 }
};


foreach (var item in list)
{
     try
     {
          dbContext.Candidates.Add(item);
          dbContext.SaveChanges();
     }
     catch (Exception)
     {
          // Handle exception
     }
}
```

Clearly the first item will throw up a Validation Error i.e.

> Name is required.

But the second item in the list clearly satisfies the validation requirements, but I once again get Validation error i.e.

> Name is required.

What am I doing wrong here and why is the code behaving this way?

Comment: once you add an item, it is still in dbContext; remove that items in Catch when you get an exception

Comment: I've to do a dbContext.Candidates.Remove(item) ???

Comment: or you can have var dbContext = new TestDbContext(); inside for loop

Comment: no that won't work for me, I make use of repositories and stuff :)

Comment: did Removing work?

Comment: your concept is wrong. db validation should be your last line of defence against shit data. you should handle the validation on the DTO level. This approach of saving one by one record will kill your DB and makes no sense. Have a look at FluentValidation.

Comment: I don't have DTO because I'm not passing it from the view.

Comment: @techspider yes that did work...thanks

Comment: Why not just use AddCollection and than save changes? Only after adding them all together

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add a `finally` block to your `Try` `Catch` like this:

```
try
{
    dbContext.Candidates.Add(item);
    dbContext.SaveChanges();
}
catch (Exception)
{
    // Handle exception
}
finally
{
    dbContext.Candidates.Remove(item);
}
```

Comment: Will it be committed? I didn't try, but I think you have to call SaveChanges after Remove(), don't you?

Comment: @AliaksandrBortnik Well *the code inside a finally block will get executed regardless of whether or not there is an exception* so if you call `SaveChanges` after `Remove` it also removes the items from DB which have inserted correctly in the `try` block and this is not what we want. We just need to remove that item from `dbContext` so that the catch block will not rethrow an exception.

Comment: That's right, makes sense. Cleanup just for a context. Not sure about your plan if it has not been added to a context successfully.